# android Edit text Filter

Tags: android

I am working on android APP and I want to make an EditText field allow only Alpha characters in 3 languages .

I am trying to add a filter to my `EditText` Like this

```
 firstNameEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            boolean keepOriginal = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(end - start);
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                char c = source.charAt(i);
                if (isCharAllowed(c)) // put your condition here
                    sb.append(c);
                else
                    keepOriginal = false;
            }
            if (keepOriginal)
                return null;
            else {
                if (source instanceof Spanned) {
                    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(sb);
                    TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) source, start, sb.length(), null, sp, 0);
                    return sp;
                } else {
                    return sb;
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isCharAllowed(char c) {
            Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[:alpha: ]+$");
            Matcher ms = ps.matcher(String.valueOf(c));
            return ms.matches();
        }
    }});
```

It is working but the problem was : I cant write any space in my EditText .

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the whitespace character: `Character.isWhitespace(myChar)`
So e.g. in your `isCharAllowed` function, just add

```
if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in edit text.

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "
```

this property not allow other characters.